# Pointing src attribute of script tag to download js from an action method in asp.net mvc 2.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, server-push

I have the following SCRIPT tag in one of the ViewPage in MVC 2 :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Account/Handler?ms=connect"></script>
```

But, it does not download the script from that action method. I had setup a breakpoint in the `Handler` action of `Account` controller, but it does not hit. The action method is not called.

If I use this same tag in `HomeController` and point to `Home/Handler` then it downloads and action method is called.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is the correct URL?  If you are already at "http://mysite/Account" for instance, that will point to "http://mysite/Account/Account/Handler?ms=connect".  You should use Url.Action():

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<%= Url.Action("Handler", "Account", new { ms = "connect") %>"></script>
```

If you use google chrome for your browser, you can view source and click on the url to see what is returned.  Of course you need to set the content type to "text/javascript" but if it works in your home controller I assume you already to that.